Cant map <leader>c in a minimal init.lua
Here is my minimal init.lua
-- Nixvim's internal module table
-- Can be used to share code throughout init.lua
local _M = {}

-- Ignore the user lua configuration
vim.opt.runtimepath:remove(vim.fn.stdpath("config")) -- ~/.config/nvim
vim.opt.runtimepath:remove(vim.fn.stdpath("config") .. "/after") -- ~/.config/nvim/after
vim.opt.runtimepath:remove(vim.fn.stdpath("data") .. "/site") -- ~/.local/share/nvim/site

-- Set up globals {{{
do
    local nixvim_globals = { mapleader = " ", maplocalleader = " " }

    for k, v in pairs(nixvim_globals) do
        vim.g[k] = v
    end
end
-- }}}

-- Set up keybinds {{{
do
    local __nixvim_binds = { { action = "gcc", key = "<leader>c", mode = "n", options = { noremap = true } } }
    for i, map in ipairs(__nixvim_binds) do
        vim.keymap.set(map.mode, map.key, map.action, map.options)
    end
end
-- }}}

The above init.lua was generated by https://github.com/nix-community/nixvim.
It looks valid to me.
I am trying to map gcc to <leader>c.
When using the built-in gcc in Neovim, it works. But <leader>c does not.
Running :nmap shows that the mapping is there.
Running :verbose nmap <buffer> <leader>c says: No mapping found. This is strange.

For googlers from the future, here is how I solved it eventually:
{
  mode = "n";
  key = "<leader>c";
  action = "gcc";
  options.remap = true;
}

I found the answer here: https://www.reddit.com/r/neovim/comments/1d278fz/keymap_comment_nvim_010/.
In case the link stops working in the distant future, here is a quote:

If you are wondering why remap is necessary, it is because gcc is a mapping as well. So when remap is false, it will not recursively map to other mappings. You can see it and other defaults here https://github.com/neovim/neovim/blob/master/runtime/lua/vim/_defaults.lua#L135.

